# wagtail login page is endlessly looping into login page

Tags: python, django, content-management-system, wagtail, wagtail-admin

I had a dockerised setup for a python web application with wagtail as cms which was deployed in EKS. Everything on the web page seems fine, every error seems fine but I'm unable to login to wagtail portal when I'm trying doman.com/admin.

Stack I use
**Requirements.txt**

```
djangorestframework==3.11.0
Django>=2.1,<2.2
wagtail==2.5.1
# *****************************************************************************

django_compressor==2.2
django-libsass==0.7
django-multiselectfield
django-csp
django-storages[google]

elasticsearch>=5.0.0,<6.0.0

# choose mariadb or postgresql (should also be set in Dockerfile)..
mysqlclient==1.3.13

cssutils
python-dateutil>=2.7.3,<2.8
untangle==1.1.1

puput==1.0.5
# = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = =
## puput requirements..
django-el-pagination>=3.2.4
django-social-share==1.4.0
django-colorful>=1.3
## puput wp2pupt (WordPress importer) requirements..
lxml>=4.2.5,<4.3
# = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = =

uWSGI==2.0.17


boto3==1.26.125
boto
wagtailmenus==3.1.2
```

**Please let me know if you need more info, THANKS IN ADVANCE**

Explained wagtail login issue and expecting some issue with code or versions i'm using

Comment: Did you create a superuser? What is happening when you try to login? Are you getting an access denied or a 500 error or something else? What do the logs say when you have this problem?

Comment: Yes I created a super user its accepting my credentials but after some time it’s circling back to login in page